# time check every second and tuning OnDesroy

Tags: android

I make an application for getting different promotional codes for free, but I want to restrict people to take a promotional code once every 5 hours (that is, click "get", get a promotional code and the button is inactive for 5 hours), but I ran into a couple of problems:

1. How to set up to receive time every second and calculate the difference exactly while the application is running (in the code it works only if the application is minimized and the application is deployed after the right time)?
2. How to save the value of the .setEnabled () button (true or false) when the application is closed (I know that in OnDestroy, but I cannot find the command to find)?
   Thanks in advance!

   ```
   Button button;
   TextView textView;
   private String TAG;
   SharedPreferences preferences;
   Long oldTime;
   Long newTime;
   Long current;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       button = findViewById(R.id.button);
       textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
       preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);





       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               button.setEnabled(false);
               Date date = new Date();
               long startTime = date.getTime();
               Log.d(TAG,"Time: " + startTime);
               SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
               editor.putLong("Tl", startTime);
               editor.apply();

               oldTime = preferences.getLong("Tl", 0);
               Log.d(TAG, "Old Time2: " + oldTime);
               newTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
               Log.d(TAG, "New Time: " + newTime);
               current = newTime - oldTime;
               Log.d(TAG, "Current: " + current);
           }
       });


       if (current != null) {
           if (current >= 10000) {
               button.setEnabled(true);
           }
       }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
       super.onStart();

   }

   @Override
   protected void onRestart() {
       super.onRestart();

       oldTime = preferences.getLong("Tl", 0);
       Log.d(TAG, "Old Time2: " + oldTime);
       newTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
       Log.d(TAG, "New Time: " + newTime);
       current = newTime - oldTime;
       Log.d(TAG, "Current: " + current);

       if (current >= 10000) {
           button.setEnabled(true);
       }
   }


   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       button.onSaveInstanceState();

   }
   ```

Comment: Saving it to shared preferences seem sufficient (although if user reinstalls app, shared prefs will be cleared). I think you could check if user can get a code in onCreate and if he cant, then start a timer, when this timer runs out you can enable the button again. This way you dont need to save anything in onDestroy

Comment: if I understand correctly what you want to say, then it will not work, the timer is reset when the application is restarted, or paused
and my problem is that I can’t set up so that after the button has been deactivated the code starts to receive time every second in milliseconds and calculate the difference with the received startTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to set up to receive time every second and calculate the
>   difference exactly while the application is running (in the code it
>   works only if the application is minimized and the application is
>   deployed after the right time)?

No need to check every second to enable/disable get promote code button. If you need to do an action (enable/disable the button) after a specific time (5 hours in your case) then you should you `AlarmManager` API. It will work whether your app is running or not.

**Solution:** You can follow the below example how to do an action after a specific time.

**Step 1:** Define `AlarmBroadcastReceiver` class, this class will be called by `AlarmManager` after a specific time.

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext())
                .edit()
                .putBoolean("enabled", true)
                .apply();

        Intent i = new Intent("updatePromoteCode");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(i);
    }
}
```

then register in manifest file.

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmBroadcastReceiver"/>
```

**Step 2:** Write code in `MainActivity`, its layout has only one button named `button_get_promote_code`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PROMOTE_CODE_AVAILABLE_INTERVAL = 5 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // In milliseconds.

    private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;

    private Button mGetPromoteCodeButton;

    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Enable the button after the specific time.
            mGetPromoteCodeButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

        mGetPromoteCodeButton = findViewById(R.id.button_get_promote_code);
        mGetPromoteCodeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Disable the button after users click on it.
                v.setEnabled(false);

                // Save a variable named `enabled` in prefs which indicates status of the button.
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext())
                        .edit()
                        .putBoolean("enabled", false)
                        .apply();

                // Schedule an action (enable the button) after a specific time by using AlarmManager.
                mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + PROMOTE_CODE_AVAILABLE_INTERVAL,
                        pendingIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // This receiver will receive an action which sent from `onReceive` method of `AlarmBroadcastReceiver`.
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("updatePromoteCode");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

        // When this activity goes to foreground, we will set its status based on `enabled` variable in prefs.
        boolean enabled = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext())
                .getBoolean("enabled", true);
        mGetPromoteCodeButton.setEnabled(enabled);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Unregister the receiver.
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```